# How to keep TextBox vertical bar position when text is added with AppendText method continously?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How to keep TextBox vertical bar position when text is added with AppendText method continously?

Answer (score 0):

You could set it's `ScrollBars` property:

```
this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
```